# Cómo optimizar el siguiente algoritmo en Python?

Tags: python

Tengo un algoritmo basado en backtracking que tiene que hacer sublistas de tamaño x y una vez obtenidas las sublistas ver si el menor elemento de la sublista es divisor del resto de la sublista (La lista L original se supone que esta ordenada).

Me gustaria saber si es posible mejorar el codigo ya que es demasiado lento para listas grandes (el algoritmo tiene que basarse en backtracking)

```
def Sublistas (s,L,x,n,cont):
    if len(s) == len(L):
        if (n == x):
            if Valido(L,s):  # si es candidato valido añade 1 a la solucion 
                cont+=1     
    else:

        for j in range(0,2):
            s = s + [j]      #incluye el candidato
            if j==1:       #si se incluye se actualiza el contador de cogidos
                n+=1

            Sublistas (s,L,x,n)
            if j==1:    # Elimina ultima solucion y actualiza elementos
                n-=1
            del s[-1]

    return cont
```

Para

```
L = [23,13,109,6,18,5,32,24,86,52,13,33,4,63,1,19,11,1,37,26,23,8,6,68,51,31,85,20,33,52]
x=9
```

cuya sol es 7400250, tarda 1340 s

Comment: Cómo se supone que se ejecuta tu código para llegar a esa solución? qué es `s` y `n`?

Comment: `s` es una lista originalmente vacia que va llenandose de `0` o `1` segun se haya cogido ese elemento o no y  `n` lleva una cuenta de los `1` que lleva `s`

Comment: Hola, no te voy a dar una respuesta concreta porque este tipo de preguntas se brinda para opiniones, pero viendo que usas python, busca información sobre Programación Dinámica y Estocástica para optimización de algoritmos.

Comment: A menos que publiques un código completo, que se pueda copiar y ejecutar, no hay mucho más que opinar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ampliando la respuesta de [@abulafia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/7123/abulafia), en el algoritmo se está creando una `sublista` de la que podemos asegurar que todos los elementos que se le añaden serán siempre divisibles por el primer elemento, lo que ahorra muchos cálculos.

Sería algo así:

```py
def raytracing(lst, deep):
    return sublistas([], lst, deep, contador=0) 

def sublistas(sublista, resto, deep, contador):

    if deep == 0:
        contador += 1
    elif not sublista:
        for i, fst in enumerate(resto):
            # nos quedamos del resto únicamente con los divisibles
            resto2 = [k for k in resto[i+1:] if k%fst==0]
            contador = sublistas([fst], resto2, deep-1, contador)        
    elif len(resto) >= deep:
        for i, num in enumerate(resto):
            contador = sublistas(sublista + [num], resto[i+1:], deep-1, contador)

    return contador


def main():
    L = [23,13,109,6,18,5,32,24,86,52,13,33,4,63,1,19,11,1,37,26,23,8,6,68,51,31,85,20,33,52]
    L.sort()
    x=9
    r = raytracing(L, deep=x)  # eq: sublistas([], L, deep=x, contador=0)
    print(r)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Por el modo de construcción, cuando hacemos `sublista + [num]` ya estamos seguros que `num` es divisible por el primer elementos de `sublista`.

Probando tiempos:

```sh
$ python -m timeit -n 1 -r 1 -s "from raytracing import main" -- "main()"
7400250
1 loop, best of 1: 4.83 sec per loop
```

Answer (score 3):

### La fuente de ineficiencia

Tu código consume muchísimo tiempo en la forma en que genera una sublista de tamaño `x` a partir de la lista que recibe como parámetro. Debido a la forma en que está implementado, realiza muchas llamadas recursivas a sí mismo antes siquiera de extraer la primera sublista.

Por ejemplo, para una lista de entrada de 100 elementos, y siendo x=5, la función no entrará en el `if` inicial durante las primeras 100 llamadas recursivas a si misma, pues va dedicando esas primeras 100 llamadas a ir creando un parámetro inicial `s` que es una lista llena de ceros. En cada llamada recursiva añade un 0 más, por lo que no llega a tener longitud 100 hasta haber realizado 100 llamadas recursivas.

Una vez realizadas las 100 primeras llamadas, entrará en el `if len(x)==len(L)`, pero fallará seguidamente en el `if n==x`, pues `n` todavía vale 0, ya que `n` es el fondo un contador de cuántos unos hay en la lista `s` y no hay niguno. Así que aún tenemos un montón de llamadas recursivas adicionales hasta que `n` tome el valor 5.

Concretamente, ya que la forma en que los 1 se van añadiendo a la lista `s` es siguiendo una especie de "orden en binario", es decir, primero la lista tiene 100 ceros, después 99 ceros y un 1. Después 98 ceros y un 1,0. Después 98 ceros y un 1, 1.... etc, en llegar a tener 5 unos requerirá 2^5 llamadas recursivas más.

Así, por fin, tras 132 llamadas recursivas, finalmente se creará la primera sublista de 5 elementos y se testeará su validez.

### Implementación directa, sin backtracking

Como muestra te doy la implementación más rápida posible, que no usa backtracking  pero puede servirte para hacerte una idea de la ganancia de tiempos (a la vez que te pone una cota al tiempo mínimo posible).

```
from itertools import combinations

def Valido(sol):
    divisor = sol[0]
    return all(elem % divisor == 0 for elem in sol[1:])

def contar(lista, x):
  cont = 0
  for sub in combinations(lista, x):
    if Valido(sub):
      cont += 1
  return cont
```

La función `Validar()` recibe una sublista y verifica que cumpla la condición exigida. Como ves he simplificado un poco tu código, pero esa no es la parte en la que más tiempo se perdía.

El código anterior se probaría por ejemplo así:

```
L = [23,13,109,6,18,5,32,24,86,52,13,33,4,63,1,19,11,1,37,26,23,8,6,68,51,31,85,20,33,52]
L.sort()
x=9
print(contar(L, x))
```

Y genera el resultado 7400250 en 16.3 s

Aunque digo que la solución anterior no usa backtracking, es posible que sí que lo use internamente, en la función `combinations()` de la biblioteca estándar. No obstante entiendo que no es esta la solución que buscas, sino implementar backtracking en tu propio código.

### Solución con backtraking

Ya que la principal fuente de ineficiencia de tu código es la gran cantidad de llamadas recursivas innecesarias que haces para ir metiendo 1 y 0 en la lista `s`, para después seleccionar de la lista L sólo aquellos elementos que tienen un 1 en `s` (lo que es otra fuente de ineficiencia por obligar a recorrer toda la lista `s` buscando esos unos), podemos buscar otra forma de recorrer todas las combinaciones posibles de elementos sin necesidad de la lista `s` de booleanos.

Un enfoque puede ser el tener una función `Sublistas()` con sólo tres parámetros:

- `sublista` es la sublista que está siendo construida. Inicialmente será `[]`, pero en cada llamada recursiva se irá añadiendo un término, o sustituyendo el último añadido por otro (backtracking)
- `L` la lista de la cual podemos seguir tomando opciones. Originalmente será la lista completa, pero a medida que vamos tomando opciones para añadirlas a `camino`, irá menguando.
- `x` el número de elementos que aún quedan por tomar para crear la `sublista`. Inicialmente será por ejemplo x=2, o x=9, pero en cada llamada recursiva se va decrementando. Cuando `x==0` tenemos ya una sublista completa que podemos validar.

Así pues:

```
def Valido(sol):
    """Retorna True si la sublista es válida, es decir, su primer elemento
    divide a todos los demás"""
    divisor = sol[0]
    return all(elem % divisor == 0 for elem in sol[1:])

contador = 0

def Sublistas(sublista, L, x):
    global contador
    if x == 0:
      contador += Valido(sublista)
    else:
      for i, num in enumerate(L):
        sublista.append(num)               # Añadir elemento a seleccion
        Sublistas(sublista, L[i+1: ], x-1) # Llamada recursiva
        sublista.pop()                     # backtracking
    return contador
```

Esto se prueba así:

```
L = [23,13,109,6,18,5,32,24,86,52,13,33,4,63,1,19,11,1,37,26,23,8,6,68,51,31,85,20,33,52]
L.sort()
x=9
r = Sublistas([], L, x)
```

y genera el resultado correcto en `r` (7400253) en tan solo 32.2s, que no está nada mal si lo comparas con el mejor tiempo posible antes calculado (16.3s)

**Nota**. Puedes eliminar el requisito de que `L` te tenga que llegar ordenada, si en la función `Valido` cambias `divisor = sol[0]` por  `divisor = min(sol)`. De esta forma el algoritmo funcionará ya para cualquier lista, venga ordenada o no.

Comment: ya se de por si que backtracking es poco eficiente pero es una practica donde hay que implementar el algoritmo usando backtracking, la cosa es que tengo que pasar el testing con un tiempo limite de 200s y tal como lo tengo tarda 7 veces mas que el tiempo limite

Comment: @hipsilv3er La fuente de ineficiencia no es en sí el backtraking, sino la gran cantidad de llamadas recursivas innecesarias que estabas realizando. Acabo de ampliar la solución con otra implementación recursiva que usa backtraking pero que tarda mucho menos por construir las sublistas de una forma mucho más directa

Comment: Es peligroso alterar `sublista` con `.append()` y `.pop()`. Debería funcionar igual con `sublista +  [num]`. Por otro lado, se puede evitar las variables globales si se pasa `contador` como argumento.

Comment: Estaba pensando que el modo en que se construye `sublista` ya asegura que todos los elementos son divisibles por el primer elemento. Voy a añadir esta optimización como respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Si es necesario que sea con una función recursiva, podrías hacerlo así:

```
from itertools import combinations

def Validar(lista, minimo, ind):
    if ind == -1:
        return 1
    if lista[ind] % minimo != 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return Validar(lista, minimo, ind -1)

L = [23,13,109,6,18,5,32,24,86,52,13,33,4,63,1,19,11,1,37,26,23,8,6,68,51,31,85,20,33,52]
x = 9

contador = 0
for sublista in combinations(L, x):
    contador += Validar(sublista, min(sublista), x -1)

print(contador)
```

Esto te devuelve 7400250.

con `combinations` generas las combinaciones posibles, y luego vas probando la condición para cada indice. Si cumplen todos (el indice llega a -1) devuelve 1 que se suma a `contador`, en caso de encontrar alguno que no cumple, directamente devuelve 0.

Si no necesitas que sea con recursividad puedes hacerlo aún más corto:

```
from itertools import combinations

contador = 0
for sublista in combinations(L, x):
    minimo = min(sublista)
    contador += all(elemento % minimo == 0 for elemento in sublista)

print(contador)
```

Con esto para los mismos datos, también devuelve 7400250.